# Getting NDVI values using Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am new in GIS. I want a function in Python API that will give me NDVI values of a given region within specified dates. I have tried the following code but print returns `None`.

```
dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI').filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(-122.1, 37.2)).filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31') 
colorized = dataset.get('NDVI').getInfo()

print(colorized)
```

Comment: You appear to be using Google Earth Engine, and there's no indication of PostGIS use, yet the only tag is `postgis`. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the exact software in use and clean up your tags.

Comment: You have to be more specific with the output you're trying to get. Try to provide some context of this too.